# Section height does not change depending on its content

Tags: html, css

In the first section in wide-screen There is a large box on the left and 4 small boxes on its right (2 up and 2 down).
When the screen gets below 1007px, the 4 boxes get below the large box, instead of on its right.

My issue is that I can't get the first section height to match its whole content once the media's max-width is less than 1007px.
For this reason - the content of the first section overlaps with the content of the second section.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <section>
        <div class="main wrapper">
            <div class="big wrapper">
                <div class="shadow box">
                    <h2>Big heading</h2>
                    <p class="hide">Some text</p>
                    <h4>Category</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big wrapper">
                <div class="small wrapper">
                    <div class="shadow box hide">
                        <h3>Small heading</h3>
                        <h4>Category</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shadow box hide">
                        <h3>Small heading</h3>
                        <h4>Category</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="small wrapper">
                    <div class="shadow box hide">
                        <h3>Small heading</h3>
                        <h4>Category</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shadow box hide">
                        <h3>Small heading</h3>
                        <h4>Category</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color:white;
}

.main {
    height: 225px;
    margin:auto;
}

.small {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.medium {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.big {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.box {
    color:silver;
    margin: 0.3rem;
    background: center center/cover no-repeat;
    flex: 1;
}

section {border:2px solid blue;display:block;justify-self: stretch;}

@media screen and (max-width: 1007px) {
    .main {
        height: 450px;
    }    
    .big {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .small {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: First things first: this is not valid HTML. `<ul>` may only contain `<li>`, but your html has a `<div>` as the direct children of an `<ul>`. Correct the HTML first, because browsers will apply all sorts of guessing when rendering incorrect HTML and it is impossible to achieve correct results in a consistent manner if the HTML is wrong.

Comment: @sbnc.eu thanks for the feedback. changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing this one line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Add it to enable media queries.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:hover {
  filter: brightness(110%);
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  height: 225px;
  margin: auto;
}

.small {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.medium {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.big {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.box {
  color: silver;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  background: center center/cover no-repeat;
  flex: 1;
}

.box h2,
.box h3,
.box h4,
.box p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.3rem 0.2rem;
}

.box h2 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.box h3 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.medium .box h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.medium .box p {
  color: black;
}

.box h4 {
  font-size: 12.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

section {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: block;
  justify-self: stretch;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1007px) {
  .main {
    height: 450px;
  }
  .big {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .small {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .small .box h3,
  .small .box h4 {
    top: 85%;
  }
  .box h2,
  .box h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .box h2,
  .box h3,
  .box h4,
  .box p {
    position: relative;
    top: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<section>
  <ul>
    <div class="main wrapper">
      <div class="big wrapper">
        <li class="shadow box">
          <h2>Big heading</h2>
          <p class="hide">Some text</p>
          <h4>Category</h4>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="big wrapper">
        <div class="small wrapper">
          <li class="shadow box hide">
            <h3>Small heading</h3>
            <h4>Category</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="shadow box hide">
            <h3>Small heading</h3>
            <h4>Category</h4>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="small wrapper">
          <li class="shadow box hide">
            <h3>Small heading</h3>
            <h4>Category</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="shadow box hide">
            <h3>Small heading</h3>
            <h4>Category</h4>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</section>
<section>
  <p>Some more text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this line does exist in the full code and still does not work.

Comment: Ah. You want the four categories inside if the first box on smaller screens?

Comment: On a smaller screen the four small boxes moves below the big box, but the containing section’s height doesn’t change. I wish it to change accordingly